# Is it possible to use DevOps to deploy to an Azure App Service if I don't have access to Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a Azure For Student subscription through my university and I'm trying to work out how to deploy an Angular app to an Azure App Service using Azure Pipelines.

In my Release pipelines, in the step to deploy to an Azure App Service, I have to select a subscription. When I click Authorize I get the below error.

Seems I can't create a service connection because it requires access to Active Directory. I'm on my university's tenant so I don't have access to it.

Is there a way around this I can use Azure Pipelines if I don't have access to create accounts in Active Directory?

[image]

Comment: What you should do is to either ask the tenant to create a service principal for you, or create your own free organization and set up the pipeline in this one.

Comment: @Diskdrive Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As the error explicityly says, There's no way to deploy this without being a Global Admin or Owner on the Azure Active Directory tenant.

Comment: damn, are there any alternatives to accessing the app service other than creating a service connection?

Comment: @Diskdrive I am afraid it is impossible to deploy to azure app service without service connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.Ensure that the user
>   has permission to create an Azure Active Directory application.

This typically occurs when the system attempts to create an application in Azure AD on your behalf and this is a permission issue that may be due to the following causes:

- The user has only guest permission in the directory
- The user is not authorized to add applications in the directory

(1) If you only have guest permission in AAD ,please contact the admin to grant the **minimum additional permissions** to you. Let the admin to set **Guest user permissions are limited** to **No**.

(2) If you are the member of AAD, and just not be authorized to add applications in the directory. Go **User settings**, then change **Users can register applications** to **Yes** under `App registrations` section.

For details ,please refer to this troubleshoot [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation) and similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104257/failed-to-create-an-app-in-azure-active-directory-insufficient-privileges).