# Is it possible to use an Azure Classic Service Connection in my Release pipeline to deploy App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

This is a follow up to this question ([Is it possible to use DevOps to deploy to an Azure App Service if I don't have access to Azure Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380873/is-it-possible-to-use-devops-to-deploy-to-an-azure-app-service-if-i-dont-have-a)) where I can't create a service connection if I don't have access to Azure AD for my tenant.

The standard Service Connection creates a service principal which can't be done if there is no access to Azure AD. So I'm trying to see if I can create an Azure Classic Service Connection instead.

I seem to be able to create the service connection and I've verified and saved it okay.

[image]

However, it doesn't appear in the dropdown list in the Deploy Azure App Services task.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I'm trying this on a free trial tenant where I do definitely have access to Azure AD. I can't find any documentation to say Service Connections can't be Azure Classic.

If this is a restrictions for Pipelines, is it possible to deploy to an App Service in Azure without Azure AD access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Azure App Service Deploy task doesn't support classic service connections.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task):

> The task does not work with the Azure Classic service connection, and it will not list these connections in the settings of the task.